# Como verficar input text antes de fazer post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
.
.
.
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar" />
}
```

Quero verificar input usando javascript ou jquery, pra depois fazer post.

Se input for branco ou vazio, não fazer post.

Se for diferente que branco, fazer post

Comment: Qual elemento ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Atualizei post

Comment: Você usa jQuery?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) no final do carregamento da página:

```js
$(function(){
  var status = !($("input[name=lastname]").length == 1);
  $("input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', status); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar" />
```

---

Com [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) e [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

***Form:***

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" >
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar" />
</form>
```

***Js:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            lastname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            lastname: {
                required:'Digite o último nome'
            }
        }
    });  
});
```

[***Exemplo Online***](https://jsfiddle.net/ftoL3o7h/1/)

---

Com [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) e [Bootstrap Validation](https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

***Referencias:***

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.8/validator.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css
```

```js
$(function(){
 $('#form1').validator();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.8/validator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="form1" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Último nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Criar</button>
</form>
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](https://jsfiddle.net/9kn7ne5m/)

Comment: Tem como sem desativar botão ? Tipo Jquery Validation

Comment: Tipo, quando clicar botão update, verificar input e mostrar aviso vermelho

Comment: Sabe o que aconteceu a sua pergunta ficou confusa verificar input me pareceu se ele existe na pagina, seria então se o input tem valor digitado?

Comment: Isso, se não tem valor digitado mostrar aviso vermelho como se fosse "campo obrigtório"

Comment: Com Jquery e JQuery Validation pera um pouco simular exemplo.

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo que precisava

Comment: @MatheusMiranda dá uma olhada nesse https://jsfiddle.net/wgrg3z17/10/

Comment: Uau, ficou bonito esse

Comment: Vou adicionar na resposta também @MatheusMiranda

Comment: Demoro, muito obrigado por me responder

Answer (score 1):

Se não for usar nenhuma validação mais complexa, você pode utilizar `required` do HTML5 [Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) não sendo necessário JavaScript. Dessa forma:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" required>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar">
```